# Opening android or IOS apps when it is installed on phone else to store in Mendix PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, mendix

I build a PWA in Mendix. Now i try to achieve to open an app direclty based on android or ios agent. Now i just redirect to the diffrent appstors. But is there a possibility to open an app direclty by its package name?

I read alot about intents and some javascript function but when i copy paste them my compiler in Mendix said there is a compiling error on Intent function. Do i need to import something else?

Is it even possible to open apps directly from a PWA (on mobile ofcourse) on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

For android i use:

```
location.href = "market://launch?id=" + incoming_obj;
```